# SQL - if person has x vehicle, then exclude person entirely

Tags: sql, ssms

I need help with a query.

If a person has a HONDA vehicle, I need to exclude them even if they have another vehicle as well. So standard WHERE NOT IN ('Honda') will not work. Because it still displays all other vehicle types.

Here is a sample table.

| Person | Vehicle |
| --- | --- |
| Person1 | Buick |
| Person1 | Honda |
| Person2 | Toyota |
| Person3 | Tesla |
| Person4 | Ford |
| Person4 | Honda |
| Person5 | Airplane |
| Person5 | Kia |

I want to only display Person2, Person3, and Person5, for this sample. How to exclude Person1 and Person4 because they have a Honda? I do not want to display the other vehicle they drive - want to exclude the person entirely. I have tried CTE but possibly my syntax is incorrect.

```
with cte as (
  select distinct person
  from person)
select cte.*
from cte
where not exists 
  (select * 
   from vehicles Table2 
   WHERE Table2.vehicle = person.vehicle 
   and cte.vehicle NOT IN ('Honda'))
```

Or maybe CTE is not good for this scenario? Appreciate help, thank you.

Edited to add: My output keeps removing the Honda vehicle values but I want to remove the PERSON who drives a Honda + drives another vehicle. I do not want to only remove Honda.

Comment: Hi - please update your question (using editable text) to show the SQL you’ve managed to write

Comment: Please share the type of database you're using as well.

Comment: If you want to keep your not exists idea, the correct query will be SELECT DISTINCT person
FROM vehicles v
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM vehicles WHERE person = v.person AND vehicle = 'Honda'). But I recommend to use conditional aggregation because I think it's easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some conditional aggregation here:

```
select person 
from t
group by person
having Max(case when vehicle = 'Honda' then 1 end) is null;
```

Comment: I would also take this option. We could also write HAVING COUNT (CASE WHEN vehicle = 'Honda' THEN 1 END) = 0

Comment: GROUP BY ct.ClientCode
HAVING SUM(case when M.Code = 'HONDA' then 1 else 0 end) = 0)

Many thanks! The GROUP BY + HAVING SUM logic worked. I was able to eliminate the person that had a HONDA + another value. Appreciate all of the help with this!!

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to use a CTE (Common Table Expression) for this task is good, but it seems there's a bit of confusion about how to use it.

One way to solve this is by using a subquery that selects all the persons who have a 'Honda', and then exclude these persons from the main query.

Assuming the table name is Vehicles, the query would look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Person 
FROM Vehicles
WHERE Person NOT IN (
    SELECT Person
    FROM Vehicles
    WHERE Vehicle = 'Honda'
);
```

This query first selects all the distinct persons who have a 'Honda' in the subquery, and then it selects all the distinct persons who are not in that list in the main query. As a result, it excludes all persons who have a 'Honda'.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and it still continues to pull back all the people. It only removes the Honda vehicle but not the person entirely.

Comment: It shouldn't. There must be something more going on

Answer (score -1):

SELECT PERSON, VEHICLE
FROM CTE
WHERE PERSON NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT PERSON
FROM CTE WHERE VEHICLE = 'HONDA'
);